# What is the source of the different forms of Lord Narasimha?

Tags: narasimha

Lord Narasimha appeared to kill Hiranyakasipu and the incident is mentioned in Srimad-Bhagavatam. Soon after this incident, Sri Vishnu went back to Vaikuntha.

Why are there then different forms of Lord Narasimha? What are names of the different forms and what are the scriptural sources?

Comment: In Chennai, we have PADALATHIRI NARASIMHA, near Chengalpettu!!! where NARASIMHA has third eye and history of that temple says, he came and sat there after he killed..Hiranyakashipu.. The ugra form of NARASIMHA is called PADALATHIRI!

Comment: https://tamilnadu-favtourism.blogspot.com/2016/08/padalathri-temple-narasimhar-temple_96.html?m=1